# iOS5 Core Plot fit plot to visible area

Tags: ios5, core-plot, iphone-4

I got a plot for which I defined the Y range as -2000 to 2000

```
 plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(1) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(600)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-2000) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(2000)];
```

The plot is fitted to the graph along the X axis, causing the majority of the Y axis to be cut off. How can I ask the core plot to autoscale the Y axis to make the maximum value in a series just touch the top of the screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot ranges are defined by a location and a length, similar to `NSRange`. To make a range that spans between -2000 and 2000, your `yRange` should have a location of -2000 and length 4000.

You can autoscale a plot space using the `-scaleToFitPlots:` method. Several of the Core Plot example apps use this method to fit plots to their data.