# How to reset XY axis scaling point in core plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-plot

I am implementing core plot framework for graph plot, but I am not able to understand following issues :

1. How to change the scaling point on XY axis. For example right now by deafault it is showing points on x axis is 1,2,3,4,5....etc and on y axis 1,2,3,4,5,....etc and I want on y axis 100,200,300,400,...etc.
2. How to set the coordinate of whole graph, means as I run my app the graph is totally downside and not visible and to see the graph I have to drag it upside.

Please help me out ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741528/how-to-give-names-in-piechart-each-slice-coreplot-iphone/8741776#8741776

Comment: @MuditBajpai I have already done it. but the problem is that i want to reset the scaling point of X and Y axis. and also want to change the graph coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You control the visible data using the `xRange` and `yRange` of the plot space. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829660/ios5-core-plot-fit-plot-to-visible-area) for an example.

There are several options for setting up the labels, controlled by the `labelingPolicy` property. One of the pages in the Plot Gallery example app shows samples of all of the labeling policies. Which one you choose depends on how much you know about the range of data that will be displayed and whether the user can scroll and/or zoom the graph.

Answer (score 0):

1)  `y_axis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(100); // for 100 ,200 .....`

2)

`plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;`
   `plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction  = YES;`

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.99) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(7.5)];

plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-4.9) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(45)];
```

// you can visible directly graph... or you can set start location as 1st parameter and length as 2nd parameter